# how drawable folder to use to fit background images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-background

i am using API 16 (Jellybean),  4.0 WVGA (480x800: hdpi)

and i am trying to set a 480x800 image in background

i put a image in "drawable-hdpi" but this image is not fitting in background, why this is not fitting in background when  i am using 4.0 WVGA (480x800: hdpi) and same as image size

how drawable works to fit image:

**this is my code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.newapp.Firstscreen$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**see screenshot:**

http://s15.postimg.org/u8rkm6rhn/frghfghfgh.png

Comment: set `<ImageView android:scaleType="fitXY" ... />`

Comment: the other question is why aren't you setting your background to RelativeLayout `<RelativeLayout ... android:background=@drawable/background" ...>`

Comment: i am using" RelativeLayout" see my code in description

Comment: Yes, and what is the problem?

Comment: Remove all paddings from your RelativeLayout and use `android:background` instead of `android:src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either do it this way

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     
    tools:context="com.example.newapp.Firstscreen$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_paren"
        android:layout_height="match_paren"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

OR

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        tools:context="com.example.newapp.Firstscreen$PlaceholderFragment" >
<!-- CONTENT HERE -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanx: This worked well "android:background="@drawable/background""

Answer (score 1):

Change `Height` and `Width` of `ImageView` to `match_parent`.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />
```

Edit-

Complete code-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.newapp.Firstscreen$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do not forget to delete the padding from the super `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Yes @A.S. is right but little value of padding is Ok. Like 5dp.

Comment: If you want to fill complete screen then remove all padding attributes in RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your ImageView

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

and set the width and height as match_parent.